# How to run a Java Swing application from Linux shell without a desktop environment?

Tags: java, linux, swing, xserver

I have an example Java application for testing. It uses the Java Swing library. I try running it with `xserver` in the Linux shell, so I'm not using a desktop environment.

Usually, you can run e.g. Firefox without problems like this:

```
startx /usr/bin/firefox
```

I tried exporting `DISPLAY` and running the application headless, but it only printed the first of the following lines.

```java
{
    System.out.println("This works");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This should show up");
}
```

If I run `java -jar app.jar` from the command line, I get a following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

With `startx java -jar app.jar`, the output is:

```
Bad command line option "-jar"
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: So, if I run "java -jar app.jar" from command line, I get following error message: `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.` At "startx java -jar app.jar", the output is: `bad command line option "-jar"`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
startx /usr/bin/java -jar app.jar —-
```

Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/697978/how-to-pass-a-program-and-its-arguments-to-start or the startx manual page.

Edit: updated based on @chief654’s response.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. It didn't worked for me, I had still the same error. But it was right, I researched a bit and found out that sometimes you need the whole path. So I had to write /usr/bin/java instead of java. The full command was "startx /usr/bin/java -jar app.jar --". It worked then for me, thank you very much.